# Easy recurrence relation after finite difference discretization: what is the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I need a check on the solution of a linear recurrence that arise after a finite difference discretization of the problem
$$\begin{cases}
-\mu u'' + b u' = -b \\
u(0)=u(1)=0 
\end{cases}
$$
with $b$ and $\mu$ constants.  The discretization is easy and it's not relevant here, **the fact is that I end up with  this linear difference equation**: $$(\text{Pe}-1)u_{i+1} - 2 u_i -(\text{Pe}+1)u_{i-1} =  \text{Pe} h$$

where $\text{Pe}= \frac{bh}{2\mu}$ is constant.

I know that the solution should have the form $$u_i = \rho^i$$ so plugging into the equation I obtain $$(\text{Pe}-1)\rho^2 -2 \rho - (\text{Pe}+1) - \text{Pe} h=0$$

Solving the quadratic equation I find: $$\rho_{1,2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{\text{Pe}^2 (h+1)+\text{Pe}h}}{\text{Pe}-1}$$

Now, the solution should be of the form $$u_i = A_1 \rho_1^i + A_2 \rho_2^i$$, with $A_1,A_2$ to be determined by the boundary conditions.

**So far, is everything correct? I need to be sure that this is oka, in order to find $A_1,A_2$**

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake. First you have to get the general solution $u^c_i$ to the homogeneous equation
$$(\text{Pe}-1)u_{i+1} - 2 u_i -(\text{Pe}+1)u_{i-1} =  0 $$
whose solution has the form
$$ u_i^c=c_1\rho_1^i+c_2\rho_2^i. $$
Here $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are roots of
$$(\text{Pe}-1)\rho^2 -2 \rho - (\text{Pe}+1)=0.$$
Then get a particular solution $u^p_i=-\frac{\text{Pe}h}4$ to
$$(\text{Pe}-1)u_{i+1} - 2 u_i -(\text{Pe}+1)u_{i-1} =  \text{Pe} h. $$
Thus you will have the solution
$$ u_i=u^c_i+u^p_i. $$

Comment: Oh right, but I can't understand how you found the particular solution. How did you do? @xpaul

Comment: Since the right hand side is constant, so a particular solution is a constant too.

Comment: That's right, but my problem is that I can't actually find your expression. How did you derive it? @xpaul

Comment: Let $u_i=x$. Then $$ (Pe-1)x-2x-(Pe+1)x=Peh$$ and you will get $x=-\frac{Peh}{4}$.